# Sequelize throwing Invalid value [Function] on Update

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update an existing record, aiming to update the timestamp only, but whenever I execute this simple query I get an error message saying: `Invalid value [Function]`

This is the query code:

```
await db.Notification.update({
            updatedAt: moment().format()
        }, {
            where: {
                $and: [
                    { 'permit_id': { $eq: id } },
                    { 'user_id': { $eq: req.currentUser.id } },
                ]
            }
        });
```

Haven't found any solutions online regarding this issue, I also want to emhphasize that this following code works without a problem:

```
await db.User.update({
            refreshToken: null
        },{
            fields: ['refreshToken'],
            where: {
                id: req.currentUser.id,
            }
        });
```

Even though they are unrelated, I've tried similarizing them and yet still received the same result.
I have also tried:

- Updating another field rather than the timestamp.
- Specifying a hardcoded string to the updatedAt value
- Sticking to a single where query with or without an operator like `where: { user_id: { $eq: req.currentUser.id } }` where both of the field and value are of type integer or string if without the operator
- Left the update fields as an empty object
- Specified the field I am trying to update in the `fields` object like listed in user update query

Getting overheated by probably a simple mistake or a thing that I've missed. Any ideas please?

Comment: have you tried just `updatedAt: moment()` instead of `updatedAt: moment().format()` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I get this feeling that it is not the parameters that are at fault

Comment: Anything new ? i struggle too with this

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite resolve this issue but rather found a workaround. I upgraded my Sequelize to use typescript and that worked for me.

Another workaround was to use a raw update query and/or specifying query type for update. e.g:

```
totalEarnings = await db.sequelize.query('SELECT SUM("priceEstimate") FROM  "Orders" WHERE "assignedCarId" IN (:id)', {
  replacements: {id: carIds},
  type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```